# SMTP Proxy Daemon on Android

Tags: android, service, proxy, smtp, daemon

I need to develop an Android Application for my Master Thesis that allows users to send emails through a service that performs some filtering and modifications to the mail content before sending it.

For this matter, I see two alternatives: either implementing this on top of an opensource email client (such as [K-9 Mail](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/)) or by developing a transparent SMTP proxy service. Since no changes (besides configuration) in email clients would be required for the latter, this would be the preferred solution.

As I am a newbie to Android Development (I know the principles of Activities, Services, etc but no real experience apart from *"Hello World"* tutorials), I would like to ask if is it feasible to consider developing an SMTP proxy daemon-like service on Android, and how can I do it, since it has been very difficult to get help in this topic.

Thankful in advance (and sorry for my sloppy english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Find an open source Java SMTP proxy server, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/mireka/) or [this one](http://code.google.com/p/baton/).

Step #2: Try compiling the source code as part of an Android project and fix any compilation problems you encounter (e.g., missing classes).

At this point, you will know whether or not it is possible. If things are going OK, then:

Step #3: Create an Android `Service` that hosts the proxy server.

Step #4: Add in your "some filtering and modifications to the mail content" logic.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I'll also have to check if is there a way to run a Service on boot (so that the proxy server would start with the system boot). :)

Comment: @Ricardo Sousa: To get control at boot time, you need to have a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest for `BOOT_COMPLETED`, which can then call `startService()` on your service. Here is a sample project for `BOOT_COMPLETED`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot